# stpトポロジーチェンジについて

Tags: network

現在、スパニングツリーについて勉強しているのですが、Topologyチェンジが発生した時の動作で分からない事があります。
その前に、ネットワーク構成図についての説明なのですが、Switch0をルートブリッジとして、その他のスイッチもプライオリティを下げて、★の箇所がブロッキングポートになるように調整しております。そこで質問です。

✖の箇所(switch0 fa0/1--fa0/1 switch1)間をリンクダウンさせると、Topologyチェンジが発生し、ブロッキングポートがSwitch3 fa0/1のみになります。
ここまでの動きは理解できたのですが、✖の箇所(switch0 fa0/1--fa0/1 switch1)間を復旧(リンクアップ)させた時に、Switch3 fa0/1がブロッキングポートのままです。
(Switch2 fa0/3と同様にブロッキングポートになっています。)

本来、Switch3 fa0/1ではなく、Switch4 fa0/1がブロッキングポートになると考えているのですが、考えが間違っているのでしょうか？どなたか、ご教示頂けますと幸いです。

---

[image: ネットワークtopology]

Comment: 各リンクのパスコストはすべて同じ前提でしょうか。

Comment: はい、各リンクのパスコスは全て同じ前提です。